# JPA, Eclipse, and Entity constructors?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jpa

I am using EclipseLink JPA Support (Eclipse Kepler). I design my tables in MySQL and then use the JPA - Entities from Tables feature to generate the entities automatically. I am then coding the DAOs by hand.

It seems this process always generates a blank constructor. But a new entity object often needs additional initialization. e.g. created=now, didsomething=false, etc. By default, everything is null.

In the MySQL table, all these fields can have a default value. But how do you get the JPA generation to include this info in the constructor?

If I was doing it by hand, I would just code a constructor appropriately. But then if I make a change to the table, I will lose it if I regenerate it...

What is the correct way to deal with this issue?

Should I use a Factory to create and initialize the objects? Is there a way to get EclipseLink to generate an appropriate constructor? Basically, I'm trying to deal with issues caused by nulls. Nothing complicated...

What is the best practice?

Thanks

Comment: The best practice is to code your entities by hand. They should indeed have custom constructors, business methods, appropriate comments, etc. etc.